# eigenstructure matching optimization

Tags: optimization, eigenvalues, differential-equations

Is there any optimization loss functions that can approximately match the eigenstructure of the original samples and the transformed samples?

For example, given a collection of samples $\mathbf{X}$ that are not *i.i.d*, the eigenvalues of the covariance matrix $\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}$ may have a few salient eigenvalues and many other trailing ones. I hope to train a model $f()$, where $f(\mathbf{X})^Tf(\mathbf{X})$ shows a similar eigenstructure. There may be scale differences, so I need to match the normalized eigenvalues whose maximum value is 1.

Both normalization and eigendecomposition are not differentiable, so it does not look like I can directly write the described into a loss function and optimize for it.

I wonder if there are approximations can do this.

Comment: why bother? what's the purpose of $f$?

Comment: @carlo I try to make it as a regularization of an MLE problem.

Comment: that's not really helpful. which is a good $f$ and wich is not? similar eigenstructure is a criterium, but I assume usefulness is also required, and I don't know how to figure it.

Comment: @carlo I'm not sure what you mean by usefulness, but I try to train a model $f$ (which maps data into a label) by minimizing $||f(x)-y||_2^2 + \lambda R$, where $R$ is the regularization I need above.